# Cannot delete '' from a column of my dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with the column price and I need to change the data type to float64.

This is da data of price when I open de dataset with pandas:

```
0           29.9
1           39.9
2         499.99
3         539.99
4         519.99
           ...  
397729    139.99
```

When I try to change it i get this message ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

When I try to see where this '' "empty spaces or whatever they are" this is what I see:

```
df.price.apply(lambda x: x.replace('','x'))
```

```
0             x2x9x.x9x
1             x3x9x.x9x
2         x4x9x9x.x9x9x
3         x5x3x9x.x9x9x
4         x5x1x9x.x9x9x
              ...      
397729    x1x3x9x.x9x9x
```

I have tried replacing the values twice but it stay de the same, with the '' in the middle.
I cannot replace them with 0 cause I need the values.

I need my data like this but been able to change it to float.

```
0           29.9
1           39.9
2         499.99
3         539.99
4         519.99
           ...  
397729    139.99
```

Comment: There are possibly some empty price values in your data. What is output of `df[df["price"].str.strip().str.len() == 0]`?

Comment: I get the following:
           Price       Other_Column1      Other_Column1
8754  0643131504438 65-1-317
9121  0655257738062 65-1-317
9122  0655257738246 65-1-317
17718  3014260014445 65-1-317
17751  3014260019723 65-1-317
... ... ... ...
391928  8004200128702 65-1-317

When I do that the price column is apparently empty.

Comment: You can try @Ynjxsjmh's solution below. It will convert any such invalid numbers to NaN.

Comment: Thanks mate. How can I see which values are NaN?

Comment: Please refer example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_numeric`

```py
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: It works, thanks Ynjxsjmh. How can I see which values are NaN?

Comment: @oscarmarinoa Use `df.loc[df['price'].isna(), 'price']`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"],
                    "price": ["29.9", "39.9", "499.9", "539.99", "519.99"]})

print(type(df["price"][0]))

df = df.astype({"price": float})

print(type(df["price"][0]))
```

Result:

`<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>`